# Using Part of prefab as script parameter

Tags: unity, prefabs, scriptable-object

I'm trying add a weapon to Eithan - the third person character. So I want to take his hand, which is part of the prefab Eithan (the weapon location) and use it in the my Player.cs script to Instantiate the weapon.
I created a parameter in the script for the hand: [SerializeField] GameObject weaponSocket; and I tried to Instantiate the weapon like this like this: Instantiate(weaponPrefab, weaponSocket.Transform);, but I just cant drag the hand to the parameter.

Anyone knows how to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Images: Player script:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable {

[SerializeField] Weapon weaponInuse;
[SerializeField] GameObject weaponSocket;

GameObject currentTarget;
CameraRaycaster cameraRaycaster;

// Use this for initialization
void start ()
{
   PutWeaponInHand();
}

private void PutWeaponInHand()
{
   var weaponPrefab = weaponInUse.GetWeaponPrefab();
   var weapon = Instantiate(weaponPrefab, weaponsocket. transform);
   weapon.transform.localPosition = weaponInUse.gripTransform.localPosition;
|  weapon.transform.localRotation = weaponInUse.gripTransform.localRotation;
```

[image]

Trying to drag the left hand to the parameter (indicated by red arrows):
[image]

Comment: Try changing it to `[SerializeField] private Transform weaponSocket;` Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: didnt work, same thing happens

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like you've selected your player prefab in the Assets folder, then tried to drag the hand *from the instance in your open scene* into  its inspector. This will not work because a prefab cannot reference a scene object. You should select the Player instance in your scene, then try it on the instance. Then you can apply that change back to the prefab in your assets folder by applying the override.

Comment: Please post code as formatted text rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you can do is to use the method FindGameObjectsWithTag.
Add a special tag to your hand and use this:

```
GameObject hand = FindGameObjectsWithTag("HandTag")[0];
```

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Comment: Keep in mind that `Find` does a string comparison with every child of the game object, which can be quite slow for more complex ones. So it should be voided if possible. And if you *have* to use it (usually you don't) you should cache the result.

Comment: Yes clearly, but his script will only use it one time I think. So it won't be time consuming. But it surely exists a better idea

Comment: Hey, just tried it, it works for EthanBody or hips, but for some reason  it returns null for the hand

Comment: Have you write the correct name?

Comment: yep.. copy paste :)

Comment: it returns null for EthanLeftUpLeg as well

Comment: Can you show code for that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/nRgwOdf
code in debug shows the values

Comment: Ok let me edit my answer, I see the problem. Find does not check all child, just the direct one.

Comment: Yep, that works. thank you.
Can u tell me why the approach I took in the question didnt work? use the hand itself as the parameter?

Comment: I think that, maybe, you should declare the variable as public and not implicitly private. Instead of using the SerializeField, try using Public GameObject weaponSockets; But I think you dont want it to be accessed by everyone

Comment: I succeded in doing it the way I wanted. when I opened the prefab until now i dragged the hand from the hirearchy to the player prefab I opened from the resources. For some reason it didnt work. But when I dragged the hand to the player prefab I opened from the hierarchy it worked

Comment: Never use `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` (or any `Find` function that uses a string) for anything. It is a messy, expensive solution that makes your code more difficult to follow and can break if you rename the tag.

Comment: Ok I didn't know, it's a method I heard about recently. I'll note for my projects :D

Comment: Also, if you create a separate tag for every game object, you are going to end up with a ton of tags. And because every object can only have one tag at a time, you lose the ability to use tags for any other feature. I prefer to not use tags at all and use marker-components instead which I detect with `FindComponent`(s)`InChildren<Component>()`.